# How can I get matrix with my own value

Tags: matrix

I want to get 1000 rows and 20 columns with prob value.

```
set.seed(12345678)
N<-1000 #row number
kitem<-20 # col number
result<- matrix(0,N,kitem)
for(i in 1:N){
for(j in 1:kitem){
theta1<-rnorm(20,0,1)
theta2<-rnorm(20,-0.5,1)
a1<-rnorm(20,1,1)
a2<-rnorm(20,1,1)
b=1
d<- -b*sqrt(a1^2+a2^2)
cc=0.5 
prob<- cc+(1-cc)/(1+exp(-((theta1*a1)+(theta2*a2)+d)))
}
}
result[i,j] <-prob
```

Comment: If someone answers "Can you help me?" faithfully and correctly with "no", that would not help you much, so that is never a good question to ask. What is not working in the code your presented? Please update the question with any error message, expected results and/or actual results

Comment: Your code looks like R; if it is, then please tag your question accordingly, to draw expert attention.